# I managed to get the command prompt to open, now how do I get it to write lines?

Tags: c#, command, prompt, cd

Basically, I want the command prompt to type and execute the command "cd/" by itself. Here's the code I used to open the command prompt: (Windows Form Application Visual c#)

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
        cmd.Start();

    }
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you have researched this?

Comment: I have been researching a way to do this for a few hours now, trying many different pieces of code and nothing worked until Steve gave me a working piece of code (Below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Arguments property of the StartInfo property to pass /K (keep windows open) and CD / (change to root)

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process cmd = new Process();

    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/K CD /";
    cmd.Start();

}
```

Comment: another question, how do i add more than one argument, so after it opens "CD/" , it would do another argument to get to openSSL (cd OpenSSL-Win64/)

Comment: The simplest way is to use a batch file passing it as argument with the WorkingDirectory correctly set.

Comment: I tried @"/k cd/openssl-win64/bin/" which worked, but when i tried to get it to create a CSR ("openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privatekey.key") the command prompt says "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: I think you should experiment with the WorkingDirectory property of the StartInfo IE [ProcessStartInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)